# Получить список дисков через WINAPI на удаленном сервере

Tags: windows, winapi

Можно ли через WinAPI получить список дисков или эта задача решается только с помощью WMI?

P.S Информация просто интереса ради. Так как `Total Commander`, например, получает лейблы расшаренных дисков. Возможно, через WMI но все же может быть есть какая-то WinApi функция.

Comment: Через удаленный реестр может быть? `RegConnectRegistry` и оттуда вытаскивать?

Comment: А Powershell подойдет? Если активирована система **WinRM** или что-то подобное, то можно выполнить удаленный скрипт. Хотя признаю, что powershell, скорее всего, опросит систему через WMI-класс **Win32_Volume**

Comment: @freim. Хм... Наверное, это рабочий вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Физические диски можно получить через Setup API. Как-то так (С++):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Setupapi.h>
#include <LM.h>
#define INITGUID
#include <Devpkey.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"Setupapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"Netapi32.lib")

void ErrorMes(LPCTSTR lpszFunction)
{
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL);

    // Display the error message 

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen(lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    wprintf(L"%s failed with error %d: %s",
        lpszFunction, dw, (LPSTR)lpMsgBuf);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}

void PrintDisks(const GUID * guidInterface) {

    DEVPROPTYPE dpt = 0;
    wchar_t buffer[1024] = L"";

    DWORD RequiredSize = 0;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA devinfo = { 0 };
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA deviceInterface = { 0 };
    PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA deviceInterfaceDetail = NULL;
    BOOL res;

    USE_INFO_2 info;
    info.ui2_asg_type = USE_WILDCARD;
    info.ui2_local = NULL;
    info.ui2_domainname = (LPWSTR)L"DOMEN";
    info.ui2_username = (LPWSTR)L"User";
    info.ui2_password = (LPWSTR)L"123";
    info.ui2_remote = (LPWSTR)L"\\\\server\\IPC$";  

    DWORD parm = 0;
    DWORD dwRes = NetUseAdd(NULL, 2, (LPBYTE)&info, &parm);
    if(dwRes != NERR_Success)printf("NetUseAdd failed: %u (%u)\n",dwRes,parm);  

    HDEVINFO deviceInfoHandle = SetupDiGetClassDevsEx(guidInterface, 0, 0, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE,
        NULL, L"\\\\server",NULL);

    if (deviceInfoHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        int deviceIndex = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            ZeroMemory(&deviceInterface, sizeof(deviceInterface));
            deviceInterface.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);

            //получение всех дисков
            if (SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(deviceInfoHandle, 0, guidInterface, deviceIndex, &deviceInterface))
            {
                DWORD cbRequired = 0;

                SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfoHandle, &deviceInterface, 0, 0, &cbRequired, 0);
                if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == GetLastError())
                {
                    deviceInterfaceDetail = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)(new char[cbRequired]);
                    memset(deviceInterfaceDetail, 0, cbRequired);
                    deviceInterfaceDetail->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

                    if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfoHandle, &deviceInterface,
                        deviceInterfaceDetail, cbRequired, &cbRequired, 0))
                    {
                        goto Next;
                    }

                    // Initialize the structure before using it.
                    memset(deviceInterfaceDetail, 0, cbRequired);
                    deviceInterfaceDetail->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

                    // Call the API a second time to retrieve the actual
                    // device path string.
                    BOOL status = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(
                        deviceInfoHandle,  // Handle to device information set
                        &deviceInterface,     // Pointer to current node in devinfo set
                        deviceInterfaceDetail,   // Pointer to buffer to receive device path
                        cbRequired,   // Length of user-allocated buffer
                        &cbRequired,  // Pointer to arg to receive required buffer length
                        NULL);        // Not interested in additional data


                    //получение информации о устройстве 
                    ZeroMemory(&devinfo, sizeof(devinfo));
                    devinfo.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
                    BOOL success = SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(deviceInfoHandle, deviceIndex, &devinfo);
                    if (success == FALSE) { ErrorMes(L"SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo"); goto Next; }

                    res = SetupDiGetDeviceProperty(deviceInfoHandle, &devinfo,
                        &DEVPKEY_NAME, &dpt, (PBYTE)buffer, 1000, NULL, 0);
                    if (res == FALSE) { ErrorMes(L"SetupDiGetDeviceProperty"); goto Next; }

                    wprintf(L"%s: %s\n", buffer, deviceInterfaceDetail->DevicePath);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

        Next:
            if (deviceInterfaceDetail != NULL) {
                delete[] deviceInterfaceDetail;
                deviceInterfaceDetail = NULL;
            }



            deviceIndex++; //следующее устройство
        }

        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(deviceInfoHandle);
    }
    else ErrorMes(L"SetupDiGetClassDevsEx");

}

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    PrintDisks(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK);
    PrintDisks(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_CDROM);
    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

Однако, этот способ не работает на Windows 10. Удаленный диспетчер устройств в ней был исключен, а вместе с ним и используемые им API.

Список букв разделов можно получить, подключившись к удаленному реестру, он хранится в ветке `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices`. Способа получить метки разделов для удаленного компьютера вроде нет.

Comment: Ох, е...=) Он же на удаленном сервере ищет? Я вопрос малость конкретизировал, на всякий случай.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Нет, не заметил вашу правку про удаленный сервер. Как сделать для удаленного, надо подумать.

Comment: Просто, тот же Total Commander эту информацию как-то получает. И собственно у меня возник интерес, а через WMI он это делает или есть хитрая WinAPI функция.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Вы про физические диски? Или про разделы (C:, D: ...)?

Comment: Разделы. Например, тотал мне показывает Label'ы разделов на которых висит шара=> если это можно получить, то и буквы получить можно.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Обновил ответ. Буквы дисков можно извлечь через удаленный реестр, а вот способа получения меток я не нашел.